# Generalization of Markov's Inequality to Vector-valued Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have some sample space $\Omega$ and a random variable (rv) $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. Then it is well known that for $a>0$
$$
P(|X-E[X]|\geq a)\leq\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{a^2}.
$$
I was wondering whether there is generalization of this result to a rv $Y:\Omega\to V$ for some arbitrary vector space $V$. In particular I am interested in an upper bound on 
$$
P(\|Y-E[Y]\|\geq a)
$$
for some norm $\|\cdot\|$. We may assume $V$ finite-dimensional if necessary.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use Markov directly:
$$P(\|X-EX\|\ge a)\le\frac{E\|X-EX\|^p}{a^p}.$$
If your norm comes from an inner product, one can easily show that $E\|X-EX\|^2=E\|X\|^2-\|EX\|^2$, which is an obvious analogue for the variance.

Comment: What is p here?

Comment: You can take any $p\ge1$.